# Do we, always, get a fix element $\alpha \in M$ such that $R\alpha=M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $M$ be a $R$-module i.e., $R$ is acting on $M$.

Do we, always, get a fix element $\alpha \in M$ such that $R\alpha=M$ ?

When is this possible and what do we say about $M$ in that situation?

If we take $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$ and fix $\alpha=1$, then clearly $R \cdot \alpha = M$ but if we fix $\alpha=2$, then $R \cdot \alpha \neq M$.

So it doesn't hold always.

If we assume that $M$ is generated principally as an $R$-module i.e., generated by a single element.

Is it possible ?

Any discussion please.

Comment: Have you heard about vector spaces?

Comment: @Bananach, Here $R$ is a ring not field, so what is your point ?

Comment: My point is that fields are rings

Comment: @Bananach, but rings are not always fields. Do you know that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't always such an element $\alpha$. When it exists, we say that $M$ is a cyclic module.

An example of a non-cyclic module is $(\Bbb Z^2,+)$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module.

Comment: Thanks. So the simple $R$-modules are also examples

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: A [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_module) of a cyclic $R$-module $M$ says $M \cong R/\text{Ann}_R(x)$, where $M$ is generated by $x$ and $\text{Ann}_R(x)$ is the annihilator of $x$. Does the opposite hold ?

Comment: i.e., let $M$ be a $R$-module such that $M \cong /\text{Ann}_R(x)$, where $\text{Ann}_R(x)=\{r \in R~|~rx=0\}$ for some $x \in M$. Does it imply $M$ is cyclic $R$-module ?

Comment: Yes, if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, $R/I$ is cyclic; take $\alpha=1+I\in R/I$.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your help